# Can't call method 'say'

Tags: perl

I have a problem with running one Perl code. It's giving me this message:
"Can't call method 'say' without a package or object reference"

The thing is, I found this code and I want to use it to check my result with sequence alignment. But it wont run.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util 'min';
use Memoize;

chomp(my $str1 = <"atattga">);
chomp(my $str2 = <"gagassa">);

my ($distance, $aligned1, $aligned2) = align($str1, $str2);
say $distance;
say $aligned1;
say $aligned2;

sub align {
    my ($str1, $str2) = @_;

    return (length($str2), ('-' x length($str2)), $str2) if !length($str1);
    return (length($str1), $str1, ('-' x length($str1))) if !length($str2);

    my @delete = align(substr($str1, 1), $str2);
    $delete[0]++;
    $delete[1] = substr($str1, 0, 1) . $delete[1];
    $delete[2] = '-' . $delete[2];

    my @insert = align($str1, substr($str2, 1));
    $insert[0]++;
    $insert[1] = '-' . $insert[1];
    $insert[2] = substr($str2, 0, 1) . $insert[2];

    my @substitute = align(substr($str1, 1), substr($str2, 1));
    $substitute[0]++ if substr($str1, 0, 1) ne substr($str2, 0, 1);
    $substitute[1] = substr($str1, 0, 1) . $substitute[1];
    $substitute[2] = substr($str2, 0, 1) . $substitute[2];

    if ($delete[0] <= $insert[0] && $delete[0] <= $substitute[0]) {
        return @delete;
    }
    elsif ($insert[0] <= $delete[0] && $insert[0] <= $substitute[0]) {
        return @insert;
    }
    else {
        return @substitute;
    }
}
BEGIN { memoize('align') };
```

Comment: You could also `use feature qw(say);` too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add this line at the begining of your script

```
use 5.010;
```

Answer (score 0):

Error message was because you have not included the package which contains the definition of 'say' keyword. Perl by default only includes 'main' package until and unless others are specified explicitly using the 'use' keyword.

use 5.010;

This will resolve the problem :)